# Build stuck due to background process in CircleCI

Tags: python, automated-tests, circleci

I have the following build configuration in my `config.yml` file for CircleCI:

```
  - run:
      name: Start API
      command: |
        . dq/bin/activate
        python3 api/run.py
        background: true

  - run:
      name: Run Tests
      command: |
        . dq/bin/activate
        nose2 --plugin nose2.plugins.junitxml --junit-xml -v
```

Basically I want to start my API with the command `python3 api/run.py` so that I can run my test in the following steps (tests are sending http requests to the API).

The `background: true` option does not seem to work as expected. The API starts but my build freezes and does not go to the following step.

Am I doing anything wrong?

[image]

Note that I have also posted this question on CircleCI forum:
https://discuss.circleci.com/t/running-flask-app-in-background/20022/2

Comment: [Cross-posted without declaration](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/running-flask-app-in-background/20022) to the CircleCI forum (complete with copy+paste tripwire). Please always declare your cross-posting.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Is it OK to cross-post a question between non-Stack Exchange and Stack Exchange website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266053/472495)

Comment: @halfler ok did not know, and beside down voting would you consider helping? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been able to run my build successfully with the following configuration:

```
  - run:
      name: Run Tests
      command: |
        . dq/bin/activate
        python3 api/run.py &
        nose2 --plugin nose2.plugins.junitxml --junit-xml -v
```

This one worked as well and seems to be a better practice as it's using the flag `background: true`. I was not indenting it properly in my previous attempt.

```
  - run:
      name: Start API
      command: |
        . dq/bin/activate
        python3 api/run.py
      background: true

  - run:
      name: Run Tests
      command: |
        . dq/bin/activate
        nose2 --plugin nose2.plugins.junitxml --junit-xml -v
```